# how to run specific test in VS code with python test explorer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have settings.json

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\tests",
    "launch": {

        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}\\.env",
    "pythonTestExplorer.testFramework": "pytest",
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\venv\\Scripts\\pytest.exe",
```

and .env

```
WORKSPACE_FOLDER=C:\work\autotests\project
PYTHONPATH=${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}
```

I want to set up "Python Test Explorer for VS code" for pytest . With this settings explorer collecting and running all tests without any problem, but when i try to run single test i get the error ERROR: file or directory not found. I think this is because explorer is collecting/running all tests by command with absolute path like "C:/work/project/tests" and running single tests with command like "./tests/test_module::TestClass::test_name", but i'm not sure. What should I do to fix this?

**Edit**

Content of Panel: `Output > Python`

```
c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest\venv\Scripts\pytest.exe --override-ini junit_family=xunit1 --rootdir c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest --junit-xml=C:\Users\EG_BAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-1984XJ6G3mxW2rt3.xml ./tests/action_log_api_test.py::TestGetActionTypes
cwd: c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest\tests
```

Comment: what is this setting: `"pythonTestExplorer.testFramework"`

Comment: what do you see in the `OUTPUT > Python` panel when you run a single test

Comment: ```
 c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest\venv\Scripts\pytest.exe --override-ini junit_family=xunit1 --rootdir c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest --junit-xml=C:\Users\EG_BAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-1984XJ6G3mxW2rt3.xml ./tests/action_log_api_test.py::TestGetActionTypes

cwd: c:\work1\autotests\tms-autotest\tests
```